# windows .net cross process synchronization

Tags: c#, windows, synchronization, ipc

I need to do some cross process synchronization.

Process B should do some actions only when Process A is running.
I tried using Mutex and EventWaitHandles like this :

In Process A main:

```
EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "SOMEGUID");
```

In Process B :

```
private static bool IsProcessARunning(string mutexStr)
{
    try
    {
        EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(mutexStr);
        return true;
    }
    catch (WaitHandleCannotBeOpenedException e)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But after process A starts once the 'IsProcessARunning' method will always return true even if process A is closed.
Any idea what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Coded a small program to try to reproduce the behavior you reported. It returns false for me as expected using Mutex or EventWaitHandle. Are you sure process A is no longer running?

Answer (score 0):

replace `EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(mutexStr);` with `EventWaitHandle.OpenExisting(mutexStr).WaitOne(-1,false);` so that you may wait for the event

EDIT:

Change: `EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(true, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "SOMEGUID");`

to

`EventWaitHandle eventWaitHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.ManualReset, "SOMEGUID");`

You must call `eventWaitHandle.Set()` when starting and `eventWaitHandle.Reset()` when stoping in ProcessA

EDIT2:

Because processA might have crashed you should impement 
            `System.Diagnostics.Process[] processes = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName(procAName);` and check if it is running. If I knew how you will be using this exactly then I could possibly suggest a more appropriate solution. In this case you don't need mutexes.

Comment: This doesn't help because after process A was started once ( even if it was closed later ) IsProcessARunning always returns true. the EventWaitHandle is signaled.

Comment: updated post, and you might want to consider replacing `WaitOne(-1,false)` with `WaitOne(your_max_wait,false)` so that the thread doesn't get stuck there forever waiting for ProcessA

Comment: "You must call eventWaitHandle.Set() when starting and eventWaitHandle.Reset() when stoping in ProcessA"
This could work only if A is closed but what if it is killed and cant call eventWaitHandle.Reset?